# does List.remove() or List.removeAll() free memory usage?

Tags: java, performance, garbage-collection

I'm processing 20GB of data inside an XML and I'm using Spring Batch to accomplish that.

I mapped my XML with Jaxb2Marshaller.
This is my JAXB:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
@XmlType(name = "BILLSClass", propOrder = {
    "bill"
})
@XmlRootElement(name="BILLS", namespace = "http://www.amdocs.com/amdd/stp/GBF")
public class BILLSClass {

    @XmlElement(name = "BILL")
    protected List<BILLClass> bill;

    public List<BILLClass> getBILL() {
        if (bill == null) {
            bill = new ArrayList<BILLClass>();
        }
        return this.bill;
    }
}
```

And this BILL have many objects inside. Approximately each BILL has almost 1GB of data.

Well, I'm processing this huge XML in this way

```
public void processXML(BILLSClass billsClass){

    Iterator<BILLClass> iterator = billsClass.getBILL().iterator();

    while (iterator.hasNext()) {
        BILLClass bill = iterator.next();
        processBill(bill);
        billsClass.getBILL().remove(bill);
    }

}
```

Notice that after I call `processBill(bill)` inside the while, I remove the bill object I have just processed out of the billClass.

I want to know if the `billsClass.getBILL().remove(bill)` will decrease the memory usage in the process or do I have to do something else in order to reduce the consumption of memory.

Comment: Roughly speaking, removing all references to objects will allow a garbage collector to free those objects back to available memory. So you could dereference an entire list instead of emptying it, for instance. Typically, huge memory consumption for file i/o processes can result from a common design flaw: instead of reading in entire files, you should be streaming/reading them `n` bytes at a time. After processing what you need, you move on. Lastly, instead of `#getBILL().remove(...)`, try `iterator.remove();`

Comment: That said, if your XML file is _20GB_, you probably need to be doing streaming parsing rather than document parsing.

Comment: @Rogue what do you mean by streaming/reading them n bytes at a time? To process each bill separately, I mean splitting the whole XML in small pieces (bill)?. And if I do the iterator.remove() this will lead to decrease the comsumption of memory?

Comment: do you have enough heap to process 20GB of raw data? that will raise the heap to a lot more than 20GB. You are for sure doing something wrong.

Comment: "Streaming" vs "reading the whole file" in this case would be the difference between using a `BufferedReader` to interpret the string contents; vs. using something like Jaxb to load the entire file and parse it. And as someone else suggested, you should consider breaking up that 20gb file into more managable data. It sounds like you need a database to be honest. But perhaps try starting with splitting each bill into its own xml.

Comment: The key point is that it allows the memory to be reclaimed by the GC but does not imply immediate reclamation.

Comment: It doesn’t matter whether `iterator.remove()` will allow removing data from memory, when the starting point is to have the whole data in memory before the iteration even starts.